# How to fill the GUID property

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, guid, anonymous-types

I am trying to enter the GUID using Linq. My code of insertion:

```
  var registration = new Registration
            {
                FirstName = registrationInfo.FirstName,
                LastName = registrationInfo.LastName,
                AddressId = _dbcontext.Addresses.Max(x => x.AddressId),
                Password = registrationInfo.Password,
                EmailAddress = registrationInfo.EmailAddress,
                IsActive = true,
                IsDeleted = false,
                Archived=false,
                DateCreated = DateTime.Now
                GUID = ?
            };
```

Can anyone please help to replace the "?" with some usefull code.

Comment: Doesnt simply GUID = Guid.NewGuid() work?

Comment: And where is LINQ? This is a simple anonymous object creation

Comment: @MrMichael : Thanks it works, +1 for the quick answer.

Comment: @AndersAbel linq is not related to this question, I have fixed tags and title

Comment: Thanks everyone you all are really cool

Answer (score 3):

Use the built in factory method to create a new one:

```
GUID = Guid.NewGuid()
```

By the way, the setter of `AddressId` looks really strange. If another address has been created in between, things will fail. Use navigation properties instead.

Answer (score 0):

Depending if you need a existing, empty or new Guid one of these choices:

```
Guid.NewGuid();
Guid.Empty;
Guid.Parse("{81a130d2-502f-4cf1-a376-63edeb000e9f}"); // replace with the GUID you need
```

also see MSDN for GUID struct: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cey1zx63.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try the above

```
 var registration = new Registration
        {
            FirstName = registrationInfo.FirstName,
            LastName = registrationInfo.LastName,
            AddressId = _dbcontext.Addresses.Max(x => x.AddressId),
            Password = registrationInfo.Password,
            EmailAddress = registrationInfo.EmailAddress,
            IsActive = true,
            IsDeleted = false,
            Archived=false,
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now,
            GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
        };
```